# MagnificPopup with ajax displays loaded content above the page instead of opening it in a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, popup, magnific-popup

Instead opening loaded content in a modal, magnific popup simply prepend it in the page's body. The console did not log any errors.

Here's the pseudo code:

**CALLER FILE(It's in the exactly same order of the real one):**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<a class="popup" href="/address/to/file.php">

<script src="/helpers/magnificpopup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<link href="/helpers/magnificpopup/magnific-popup.css">
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ( ) {
    jQuery('.popup').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        alignTop: true,
        overflowY: 'scroll',
        closeOnBgClick: false
    });
}
</script>
```

**File.php's INNER HTML:**

```
<div class="white-popup-block">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
```

**The result is this:**
[image]

**Instead of(this one is an edition):**
[image]

I already tried to change the magnificpopup version, using one that works well on another application. In this attempt, i used the same JS file and a copy/paste the code from the application where it works. But the result remains the same.

Any ideas, folks?!

Thx